# 'Text to column' in excel retains last used settings

Tags: excel

'Text to Column' feature in MS Excel retains the last used delimiter(except TAB which is a defualt setting) till I close all Excel Spreadsheet and reopen it.

Wanted to understand how can I move it to TAB delimiter after any operation is performed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think this is possible without VBA. However you can just text to columns on a single cell, changing the settings back to TAB only.